# Confused by Ambiguous Reference Member Reference error in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Given this workspace example:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class Something: NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForDescriptor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: NSError?) {

    }

    func foobar() {
        self.peripheral.writeValue([], forDescriptor: 0) // I use a real value instead of 0 in real code
    }
}
```

I get errors that look like:

```
Playground execution failed: Playground2.playground:6:3: error: ambiguous reference to member 'peripheral'
                self.peripheral.writeValue([], forDescriptor: 0)
                ^~~~
Playground2.playground:5:6: note: found this candidate
        var peripheral:CBPeripheral!
            ^
Playground2.playground:1:7: note: found this candidate
        func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForDescriptor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: NSError?) {
```

So, it can't seem to decide if my `self.peripheral` code is a reference to my variable named `peripheral` or one of the delegate functions I've chosen to implement? I guess I could rename my `peripheral` variable to be something else...

But what surprises me is that if I construct what seems like a similar example, it has no issues disambiguating:

```
import Foundation

extension Int {
    func frobnicate() { }
    func barf() { }
}

class YakAttack: NSObject {
    var something:Int!

    func something(something:Int, else:Int) {

    }

    func foobar() {
        self.something.frobnicate()
    }
}
```

The `foobar()` function should have the same issue with the `self.something` reference, but it has no such problem. What's the difference?

(I am using XCode 7.3 Beta 5, which has the latest Swift version in it)

Comment: FYI, the full release of 7.3 has been released.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I checked right after I finished watching The Most Expected Apple Event Ever, and it wasn't available then. It seemed convenient with the no-osx-love theme. Good to know it showed up.

Comment: yeah, it usually takes a few hours after the event to make everything live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is it's a message passing confusion due to dealing with Objective-C protocols/datatypes. I'm not really qualified to analyze the specific, but thus far I've learned there are still some weird bugs like this that come up when dealing with both languges.

I'm guessing this will be fixed down the road, but for now you'll probably just have the change the variable name.

Comment: Yes, changing the name of the local `var` cleared things up. But I'd still like to have a clearer answer.